# ios :hover and :focus doesnt work on ipad

Tags: jquery, ios, css, hover, focus

Hi I have a hover function found at [This Page](http://mukaportraits.com.au/testimonials/) that is used to change the opacity of a div within.

This works fine on desktop and iphone, but whatever method I use It will not work on an ipad? however it does work with firefox on an ipad . I have tried, :hover :focus and even

```
          $(".stretchy-wrapper").hover(function(){
           //On Hover - Works on ios
           $(this).css('opacity','1');
   }, function(){
//Hover Off - Hover off doesn't seem to work on iOS
$(this).css('opacity','0');
```

Still no luck, can think what elese to try or find any reason for the error?

Answer (score 0):

Couldnt find a workable solution so I ended up just changing the containing div to an < a > < / a >